# transition-duration doesn't work in specific div

Tags: html, css

I try to hover every purple and text inside-in bigger when over with zoom property.

Like this:

https://i.imagesup.co/images2/9fadd677f1625d887fdbd4819af96ee4acb6fe89.png

Two problems:

1. time duration doesn't affect (try to put it in hover class and not hover class, but still).
2. When my mouse on the top of the purple it's like a loop of zoom in and out:

Here is the relevant code, thanks for the help!

** I want the duration property will be in first class for the same effect when I leave the mouse.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#divStyle1 {
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #016087;
}

#purpuleLineBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}

#purpuleLine1 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 30vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine2 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 38vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine3 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 42vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine4 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 50.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine5 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 52.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div>p {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-left: 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
}

.purpuleHover {
  zoom: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.purpuleHover:hover {
  zoom: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div id="divStyle2">
  <main>
    <div id="purpuleLineBox">
      <div id="purpuleLine1" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>100% recyclable and bio-degradable</p>
      </div>
      <div id="purpuleLine2" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>Simulates the natural ripening process, organic</p>
      </div>
      <div id="purpuleLine3" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>The quickest way to achieve the perfect avocado taste</p>
      </div>
      <div id="purpuleLine4" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>Work with Mango, Banana, Peach, and another climacteric fruits</p>
      </div>
      <div id="purpuleLine5" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>The user interface on the bag shows when an avocado is fully ripen</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [`transition-property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property), which defined the css property which the transition should handle, and not just [`transition-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration). You can do this with separate decelerations, or define them together with the shorthand [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

In addition, you'll have to replace zoom with [`transform: scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale).

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#divStyle1 {
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #016087;
}

#purpuleLineBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}

#purpuleLine1 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 30vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine2 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 38vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine3 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 42vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine4 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 50.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine5 {
  background-color: #D52C82;
  height: 7vh;
  width: 52.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div>p {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-left: 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
}

.purpuleHover {
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.purpuleHover:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="divStyle2">
  <main>
    <div id="purpuleLineBox">
      <div id="purpuleLine1" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>100% recyclable and bio-degradable</p>
      </div>
      <div id="purpuleLine2" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>Simulates the natural ripening process, organic</p>
      </div>
      <div id="purpuleLine3" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>The quickest way to achieve the perfect avocado taste</p>
      </div>
      <div id="purpuleLine4" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>Work with Mango, Banana, Peach, and another climacteric fruits</p>
      </div>
      <div id="purpuleLine5" class="purpuleHover">
        <p>The user interface on the bag shows when an avocado is fully ripen</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a transition property like this:

```
transition: transform 0.2s;
```

1) to the initial state of the element
2) to the hover state of the element

Using that the element will be animated correctly in both ways

```
initial state -> hover state 

hover state -> initial state
```